# How to change the bg color using tkinter.Label

Tags: python, tkinter

```
questiontext = "ABCDE"
label2 = tk.Label(root, text=questiontext, font=("Helvetica",16), fg='white')#
label2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2, anchor='w')
```

I want changing the label2's bg color to transparent.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: FWIW, the answers below rely on the color `'systemTransparent'`, which is only available on Mac OS X as far as I can tell. Using this on Windows, for example, will result in a `_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "systemTransparent"`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

```
questiontext = "ABCDE"
label2 = tk.Label(root, text=questiontext, font=("Helvetica",16), fg='white',bg='systemTransparent')#
label2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2, anchor='w')
```